# How to install npm modules for ijavascript

Tags: npm, ijavascript

How can I install node modules for `ijavascript`?

I tried to create a package.json in the project folder for `Jupiter` but it stills can't install anything.

Comment: 2019-10-31 jiba yang

Answer (score 0):

You can open the terminal from Launcher tab and install packages locally via npm.
Then, you can use `require('needed-module');` in code.

It would be awesome if someone told how to set node_path for nodejs kernel in jupyter notebook.

Alternatively you can use another nodejs kernel: https://github.com/IBM/nodejs-in-notebooks

List of all available kernels: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels